# How to check the generic my method received in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a set method that need to accept 2 kind of generics :

- `Map<Long,Map<String,Object>>`, and
- `Map<Long,Map<String,String>>`

However I need to set it as `Map<Long,Map<String,String>>`

I know that String is an Object, so in the parameter I can use `Map<Long,Map<String,Object>>`, however I don't want to undergo a conversion if there no need to. Using instanceof seems not working, throwing me with error:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type
>   `Map<Long,Map<String,String>>`. Use the form `Map<?,?>` instead since
>   further generic type information will be erased at runtime

Below is current codes I have now.

```
public void setRates(Map<Long,Map<String,Object>> inputRates){

    if(inputRates!=null){
        Map<Long,Map<String,String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        // if <Map<Long,Map<String,String>> do below :
        if(inputRates instanceof Map<Long,Map<String,String>>){
        //instanceof not working....   
            this.rates= inputRates;
        }else{
            // if really Map<Long,Map<String,Object>> do below - converting Object to String
            for (Map.Entry<Long, Map<String,Object>> entry1 : inputRates.entrySet()) {
                Map<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<>(); 

                Long key = entry1.getKey();
                Map<String,Object> inputMap = entry1.getValue();
                for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry2 : inputMap.entrySet()) { 
                    String key2 = entry2.getKey();
                    Object value2 = entry2.getValue();
                    if(value2!=null){
                        resultMap.put(key2, value2.toString());  
                    }else{
                        resultMap.put(key2, null);  
                    }
                }
                result.put(key, resultMap);
            }
            this.rates = result;
        } 
    }
}
```

Any idea on how I implement this?

Comment: make an overload for setRates which takes either String,String or String,Object. Using instanceof is bad design.

Comment: actually that was my first idea. However we can't overload setRates(Map<Long,Map<String,String>>) and setRates(Map<Long,Map<String,Object>>).Compiler think they are the same thing.

Comment: Yeah you're right, forgot that Java doesn't see that as 2 different types.

Comment: @Rudy does my answer address your question? :)

Comment: Yes. Will approve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a [`generic method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

```
public <T> void setRates(Map<Long,Map<String, T>> inputRates){ }
```

Then use generic type `T` in your method's body.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are erased after compilation.  So you could never use `instanceof` with a parameterized type class :

```
if(inputRates instanceof Map<Long,Map<String,String>>){
```

Using `instanceof` with  `Map<?,?>` will be useless either as it is still broader. `Map<Object, Object>` being broader than `Map<String,Object>`.

If the clients of your method declare a broader generic variable : `Map<String,Object>String,Object>`, you is stuck to cast `Object` to `String` in the processing of the `Map`.

Other option : create a new method with `Map<Long,Map<String,String>>` as parameter.
The client would call so the first one or the second according to what one manipulates.

Comment: Overload fails, Creating 2 method setRates() is disallowed. I think Compiler thinks Map<Long, Map<String, String>> is the same with the Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> .... because String is actually Object?

Comment: I am silly. The method should have distinct names because of the erasure indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload with named classes such:

```
class ObjectMap extends Map<Long,Map<String,Object>>{}
class StringMap extends Map<Long,Map<String,String>>{}
public void setRates(ObjectMap inputRates){ }
public void setRates(StringMap inputRates){ }
```

They will work as their parametrized parts but you will need to instantiate then instead.